# Q: Django - how to return data from other function on views.py

Tags: python, django

I'm kind of working on string operation, here is what i want to do
- i created a functions **gettext(request)** for getting text from *.txt files, this is the code

```
def gettext(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        f = request.FILES['file']
        for chunk in f.chunks():
            text = chunk

        return render(request, 'ecs/index.html', {'text': text, 'form': form})      
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
return render_to_response('ecs/index.html', {'form': form})
```

and then i want to get the data that i stored on **text** variable to a functions, called **preprocessing**

```
def preprocessing(text):
    pp = Preprocess()

    wordTokenize = pp.tokenizing(text)

    return wordTokenize
```

how can i use the **preprocessing(text)** method to handle data from **text** variable on **gettext** method.
i tried some tricks, but still no progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

import the preprocessing function from wherever you have it into the file that has gettext in it, and then do this:

```
def gettext(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        f = request.FILES['file']
        for chunk in f.chunks():
            text = chunk
            text = preprocessing(text)
        return render(request, 'ecs/index.html', {'text': text, 'form': form})      
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
return render_to_response('ecs/index.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: still not working sir, 
when i run your code, the output was `global name 'request' is not defined`
so i changed `preprocess(text)` to `preprocess(request, text)` and modify `text = preprocessing(text)` to `preprocessing(request, text)` and run well, thanks @IsaacRay